# python: setattr AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python

I have an object self.config which has some variables, I would like to first check if a variable ('db_password') exist in self.config and if it exists then modify the variable value something like `self.config.db_password = 'modified values'` . following is the python code

```
    if hasattr(self.config, enc_variable):
        setattr(self.config, enc_variable, f.decrypt(self.config.enc_variable.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii'))
```

AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'enc_variable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is buggy:

```py
self.config.enc_variable
```

It should be

```py
getattr(self.config, enc_variable)
```

Or

```
self.config.db_password
```